# Is it possible to load meteor application code into a node.js script?

Tags: node.js, meteor, database-migration

Specifically, I want to run database migrations using [node-migrate](https://github.com/tj/node-migrate), and I want the content of my migrations to contain Meteor code, referencing my collections, etc.

How would I do this?

Comment: Maybe you need https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-migrations

Comment: Minor tweaks to text of question, add tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate node.js modules into your Meteor application, which is probably better than going the other way around. The first approach is to use a package such as `meteorhacks:nom` which allows you do directly use npm packages in a Meteor app. The second (and from my perspective more suitable) approach is to build a package that uses 
[Npm.depends()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Npm-depends) and
[Npm.require()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Npm-require).

With `Npm.require()` you can use the npm packages just like you would with a plain `require()` statement in Node.js.

Writing packages is not so hard - check out [the official docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/writingpackages) for more verbose information.